# splitting 3 phase from phase converter to three machines

Tags: wiring

I have a metal lathe, mill and grinder, all run on three phase. I have a three phase converter and want to know the best way to split the three phase from the converter to each machine. I looked for a three phase Junction box, but cant seem to find any information on this.

Comment: How do you plan to prevent the three phase gear from starting up when the phase converter isn't running?

Comment: Also, what do you use as disconnecting and circuit protection means for the machines right now?

Comment: Come on ThreePhaseEel if you don't turn on the phase converter there is no 3 phase output. A single disconnect from the converter would be legal either on the input or output side.

Answer (score 1):

Any junction box will work most industrial sites use Hoffman boxes the size of the box depends on the conduit size and number of conduits entering. For a small setup like this a 12×12×6 box would probably be more than enough for a terminal block or splices.

Comment: I'd like to add to Ed's response - unless maybe it's built in to your converter, you really need to run that converted power into a fused switch of some sort. Maybe you can get your hands on a little used three phase sub panel or somethin that'll take a three phase breaker. Fused switches are pretty pricey, but maybe that's an option for you. That would, in a way, be your junction box.

Comment: All the phase converters I have installed have protection the supply to the converter still needs a breaker but it would be the same thing as multiple outlets on 1 circuit.